# Trackpoint Keyboard that fixes these problems

Tags: keyboards

Trackpoint keyboard already exist:
https://images.jet.com/md5/22d6695565fc48b6cb9f00191d3fd8f4.500

I'm not sure I'm using the right word, but by trackpoint, I mean the little red ball in the keyboard picture that can be used as a mouse.

But it has some problems:

1. On one end of the wired USB connection to the keyboard, there is a micro USB. I use the keyboard on my lap and slight movements can result in the micro USB still physically in the socket, but still resulting in connection problems or very weird problems like the cursor moving by itself across the screen. This forces me to connect and reconnect the keyboard a few times until it gets back to normal. If the micro USB was just a full sized USB, that it might have been able to fit in more tightly and prevent this.
2. It's not wireless USB, which is my favorite connection by far. I use the keyboard leisurely on the couch sitting in front of a large monitor or TV.

I really love the trackpoint keyboard and am not considering touchpad keyboards at the moment.

However, what are some hardware recommendations that avoid these problems? Keyboards with trackpoint that feel alright on your lap. Perhaps are there hardware recommendations with a trackpoint keyboard with full sized USB on both ends?

EDIT: Preferably not bluetooth. I have had problems with the bluetooth version of this keyboard. I don't have problems with my bluetooth headphones.

Comment: The mouse-mover in the middle of some keyboards is called a [pointing stick](http://superuser.com/a/438752/447245).

Comment: would a trackball be an acceptable alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You have almost the same model as yours, but using a bluetooth connection:
[https://www.amazon.com/ThinkPad-Compact-Bluetooth-Keyboard-TrackPoint/dp/B00C32FWJC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C32FWJC)

No wires, no connection issues and a trackpoint which is all you asked for.

A bit expensive though...

**EDIT**
After the comments about the non-reliability of the ThinkPad bluetooth keyboard, and since I cannot find any other wireless keyboard with a trackpad, an idea came to my mind: using a standard, wired ThinkPad key board (such as http://amzn.to/2a7ekRo, something that you already have) and link it to a wireless usb hub (http://amzn.to/2atdCRv). Definitely not the prettiest solution but it can free you out from short cable while in front of tv.

Comment: I'm the OP. I didn't do that the -1 that I see here right now. I tried that bluetooth keyboard and it has some problems - the trackpoint is different, very stiff - the bluetooth connection isn't very reliable compared to USB wireless and the hassle wasn't worth it.

Comment: Ok. Strange, I had a bluetooth mouse that worked well. Maybe a problem with this particular model or with your receiver. You should have told us that you are not looking for a bluetooth solution and that you tried this product which, from what you are asking for and from your current ThinkPad keyboard, is the natural choice.

Comment: You're right. Have edited the OP. Some people who have tried that keyboard have also had some problems https://www.amazon.com/ThinkPad-Compact-Bluetooth-Keyboard-TrackPoint/product-reviews/B00C32FWJC/ref=cm_cr_dp_qt_hist_one?ie=UTF8&filterByStar=one_star&showViewpoints=0

Answer (score 0):

Try to get [one of the predecessors](http://www.notebookreview.com/notebookreview/lenovo-thinkpad-usb-keyboard-review/) of the keyboard you have. That would at least solve one of the two issues you mentioned.

I've got three of the X230-style ones (i.e. the direct predecessor of yours, not the very old IBM one which also has a Touchpad) and it's currently my favourite keyboard. I don't like the chiclet/apple style of the new ones.

They don't have your cable problem as the USB cable is hardwired to the device and can be folded into a compartment on the bottom side of the keyboard for transport. Unfortunately pressing the cable into the small slit from the compartment to outside too often damages the cable. So I usually leave it in that slit and bend it back from the outside into the compartment for transport.

But then again, they're not wireless either. (But I do prefer wired keyboards anyways, so that's no issue for me.)

The only other issue I have with these keyboards: The labels on often used keys wear off after a while (i.e. years of daily usage).

But otherwise I'm very happy with them — which is also the reason why I own three of them. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much only lenovo seems to make keyboards with trackpoints.

I've been using one with a small trackball and it works pretty well. [This specific one](https://www.iogear.com/product/GKM681R/) is made by IOGear. its not quite as awesome as a trackpoint but I find its very usable.

[image]

The keyboard has excellent travel and the keys are far enough to be usable even with big hands.

Its 2.4ghz wireless and has its own proprietary dongle . Its battery powered (Pair of AAA batteries) so no USB cables.

Has multimedia keys (if you need them) and the option of those little mouse buttons or a pair of "shoulder" buttons.